# A bilinear form $B(x,y)$ satifies $B(a,b)B(c,a)=B(b,a)B(a,c)$ implies it is either symmetric or skew-symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

If a bilinear form $B(x,y)$ satisfies for $\forall a,b,c \in V_{\Bbb{F}}$$$B(a,b)B(c,a)=B(b,a)B(a,c)$$Then $B(x,y)$ is either symmetric or skew-symmetric.

---

If I let $c=a+b$, then get $B(a,a)\left[B(a,b)-B(b,a)\right]=0\cdots(*)$. If $\text{char}(\Bbb{F})\not=2$, then $B(a,a)=0\cdots(1)$ for $\forall a \in V_{\Bbb{F}}$ $\Longleftrightarrow$$B(x,y)$ is skew-symmetric. and $B(a,b)-B(b,a)=0\cdots(2)$ for $\forall a,b\in V_{\Bbb{F}}$ means $B(x,y)$ is symmetric. But I can't deduce$(1)$ and $(2)$ from $(*)$. Could you help me?

Comment: if i'm reading your argument right, what you've essentially got is that $xy = 0$, and hence $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ since we're working over a field. that's how you get (1) and (2)

Comment: @exitingcorpse. thanks. fields have no zero divisor. but here $B(x,y)$ is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to fix your argument, but from a matrix theoretic persective, the proof is rather straightforward (despite a bit long). For convenience, I write $V$ instead of $V_{\mathbb{F}}$.

It suffices to prove the statement for the finite dimensional case, for,
if $B$ is neither symmetric nor skew-symmetric, then there exist
$u,v,x,y\in V$ such that $B(u,v)\ne B(v,u)$ and $B(x,y)\ne-B(y,x)$;
hence $B$ is neither symmetric nor skew-symmetric on the finite (actually, at most four) dimensional subspace spanned by $u,v,x,y$.

Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional. Then we can identify $B$ with its
matrix representation, and
\begin{align*}
B(a,b)B(c,a) \equiv B(b,a)B(a,c)
&\Leftrightarrow B(c,a)B(a,b) \equiv B(b,a)B(a,c)\\
&\Leftrightarrow c^\top Baa^\top Bb \equiv b^\top Baa^\top Bc\\
&\Leftrightarrow Baa^\top B \equiv (Baa^\top B)^\top\\
&\Leftrightarrow BSB=B^\top SB^\top \text{ for every symmetric matrix } S.\tag{1}
\end{align*}

If $\operatorname{char}(F)=2$, by considering every $S$ with a symmetric pair of off-diagonal ones and zeros elsewhere, $(1)$ immediately implies that $B$ is symmetric (hence also skew-symmetric).

Suppose $\operatorname{char}(F)\ne 2$. We can rewrite $(1)$ as
$$KSH+HSK = 0 \text{ for all symmetric matrix } S,\tag{2}$$
where $H$ and $K$ denote respectively the symmetric part and skew-symmetric part of $B$ (the decomposition of $B$ into $H+K$ is possible because $\operatorname{char}(F)\ne 2$). By applying a congruence transform $H\leftarrow P^\top HP,\ K\leftarrow P^\top KP$, we may assume that $H$ is a block-diagonal matrix of the form
$$
\pmatrix{\widehat{H}&0\\ 0&0_{m\times m}},
$$
where $m$ is the nullity of the linear map $x\mapsto Hx$ and $\widehat{H}$ is symmetric and invertible.
It follows from $(2)$ that in the same partitioning, all subblocks of $K$, except the leading principal one, are zero. So,

- if $H\ne0$, we can put $S=\operatorname{diag}(\widehat{H}^{-1},\ 0_{m\times m})$ and obtain $2K=0$, i.e. $B$ is symmetric;
- if $H=0$, then $B$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's unbelievable to solve it in this way.Becaue I am stupid. there are four place in the proof I can't understand. $(1)$ In the forth line, there maybe a typo: $B(u,v)\not=-B(u,v)$.   $(2)$  If $\operatorname{char}(\Bbb{F})=2$.I think $B$ can also decompose into symmetric part $\frac{B+B^T}{2}$ and skew-symmetric part $\frac{B-B^T}{2}$.$(3)$. "It follows from (2) that in the same partitioning, all subblocks of $K$, excepting the leading principal one,are zero." If $K=\begin{bmatrix}K_1 & K_2 \\K_3 & K_4 \end{bmatrix}$. Does "leading principal one" represent $K_1$ and $K_4$?

Comment: $(4)$. What is the role of the second paragraph in the whole proof? I can't find the relationship between this paragraph and the rest of the proof.

Comment: @Laura (1) Yes, that is a typo. Thanks for catching it. (2) No. If the field characteristic is 2, you cannot divide $B+B^\top$ by 2 because 2=0. (3) *Leading* means the first one, i.e. $K_1$. (4) We prove by contradiction. If $V$ is infinite dimensional and the statement is false, then the statement is also false on the finite dimensional subspace spanned by $u,v,x,y$. However, in the subsequent paragraphs, we prove that the statement is true for all finite dimensional vector spaces. Hence we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: By the way, you are not stupid. It's completely natural to solve the problem in your way. Boris Novikov also tried to solve the problem (in a deleted answer) in your way, and actually, before he posted his answer, I tried to fix your argument in his way too (i.e. to consider some quotient space so that your argument can be applied). Yet there are still some gaps that I couldn't fill. So, I turned to another approach.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have understood. I get $K_2,K_3,K_4=0$ in two steps. From $KSH+HSK=0$. I first choose $S=\operatorname{diag}(\widehat{H}^{-1},\ 0_{m\times m})$,get $K=\begin{bmatrix}K_1 & 0 \\0 & K_4 \end{bmatrix}$.then partition $S=\begin{bmatrix}S_1 & S_3 \\S_3 & S_2 \end{bmatrix}$, and $S_3$ is invertiable. then get $K_4=0$.

Comment: @Laura Yes, well done.